# Image serving from two different servers

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, proxy

I hope you are all doing great. My question is

I am using cantaloupe image server which serves images according to user specify parameters in url using IIIF image API v2.0

Here is the url.
https://iiif.blavatnikarchive.org/iiif/2/baf__be12495f1d825e832cd7b66f0ee30c8adda804cd6c19e627537107b714b95356/full/!1000,1000/0/default.jpg  (1000x1000 image)

https://iiif.blavatnikarchive.org/iiif/2/baf__be12495f1d825e832cd7b66f0ee30c8adda804cd6c19e627537107b714b95356/full/!512,512/0/default.jpg (512x512 image)

Image server takes time to process image for user defined dimensions and region extraction around 4sec. Therefore what i am doing is to pre generating some thumbnails using image server and storing them on amazon s3 so if user requests same thumbnail again and again I serve them pre generated thumbnail. Two benefits
1- Image server not computing it every time and load on server will be low.
2- Image serving through static thumb will be faster because it is pre generated.

Problem is now actually two servers are involved.
1- Image server for dynamic content creation. https://iiif.blavatnikarchive.org
2- Amazon s3 buckets for static thumbnails which were pre generated. assets.s3.amazonaws.com/image-name

I want to serve images using one url so end user don't redirect to different locations for same image with different sizes. So i decided to serve images using API

https://api.blavatnikarchive.org/baf__be12495f1d825e832cd7b66f0ee30c8adda804cd6c19e627537107b714b95356/full/!512,512/0/default.jpg (Apache using php)

In my api I know which request is for static thumbnail and i need to take it from s3 bucket and which one is for dynamic size and need to take it from image server. In API i need to get image using file_get_contents("url of image whether its amazon s3 url or image server url") so request downloads it first on my api server and then serve to client and client browser downloads it again which is time consuming and takes around 2s for one image which is not acceptable. Image serving time should be less than a sec. I am here to know is there a way to map my api url directly to image server and amazon server.

Like

If user type https://api.blavatnikarchive.org/baf__be12495f1d825e832cd7b66f0ee30c8adda804cd6c19e627537107b714b95356/full/!1000,1000/0/default.jpg

It should map to https://iiif.blavatnikarchive.org/iiif/2/baf__be12495f1d825e832cd7b66f0ee30c8adda804cd6c19e627537107b714b95356/full/!1000,1000/0/default.jpg  (1000x1000 image)

Or specify
https://iiif.blavatnikarchive.org/iiif/2/baf__be12495f1d825e832cd7b66f0ee30c8adda804cd6c19e627537107b714b95356/full/!512,512/0/default.jpg  (512x512 image)

Should map to directly static image thumb
https://baf-iiif-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/be12495f1d825e832cd7b66f0ee30c8adda804cd6c19e627537107b714b95356

or you can suggest me solution how i can gather things to one url? I want to keep user on my api url and dont want to use any redirection. How can i achieve this?

Many thanks.